# What's the best way to complete links on a certain WordPress Page with everything after the slug?

Tags: slug, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for the optimal approach to replace all links on a WordPress page with the segment that follows the page's slug. Currently, I'm encountering an issue where accessing the page with an additional URL segment leads to unintended redirects. Here's a relevant code snippet:

For instance, I want to transform links from https://every-outgoing-link-on-the-page.com to https://every-outgoing-link-on-the-page.com/username, where "username" corresponds to the portion accessed with the specific page "/r" as in https://my-page.com/r/username.

```
function custom_username_links_modify_links($content) {
    global $post;

    // Check if the current page is the selected landing page
    $landing_page_id = get_option('custom_username_links_landing_page');
    if ($post->ID == $landing_page_id) {
        // Seeking advice on the most effective approach
        return $content;
    }

    // Continue with link modifications for other pages
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $slug = str_replace($permalink, '', $current_url);
    $modified_content = preg_replace('/href=["\'](https?:\/\/[^"\'\s]+)["\']/i', 'href="$1/' . trim($slug, '/') . '"', $content);

    return $modified_content;
}
```

I'd appreciate insights on the best practice to address this situation. Thank you for your assistance!

Edit: I am not issuing redirects - that was my fault - but 404s

Comment: I'm assuming that `custom_username_links_modify_links()` is a callback for the `the_content` filter; is that correct?

Comment: Can you give a few more examples of URLs that you want this to work for, including what you want them to do and what they're currently doing? If some are working and some aren't, please show examples of both. It's not clear to me from the question.

Comment: @IanDunn Yes, this is the callback for `the_content`.
Every outgoing url on this page should be transformed like:
Original:
https://outgoing-link.com/
https://outgoing-link.com/shop
https://outgoing-link.com/account
https://outgoing-link.com/some-page

Result:
https://outgoing-link.com/username
https://outgoing-link.com/shop/username
https://outgoing-link.com/account/username
https://outgoing-link.com/some-page/username

Where "username" is the portion that was used calling the specific page "/r" like: https://mypage.com/r/username

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a solution that seems to work great and as expected:

```
function custom_username_links_modify_links($content)
{
    global $post;

    $landing_page_id = get_option('custom_username_links_landing_page');
    $registration_page_id = get_option('custom_username_links_registration_page');

    if ($post && $post->ID == $landing_page_id) {
        $url_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
        $url_parts = explode('/', trim($url_path, '/'));

        if (count($url_parts) > 1) {
            $element = $url_parts[1];
            $custom_username = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'custom_username', true);
            if (!empty($custom_username) && strpos($element, $custom_username) === 0) {
                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                $dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

                $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
                foreach ($links as $link) {
                    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
                    if (custom_username_links_is_safe_url($href)) {
                        $url = rtrim($href, '/');
                        $newHref = $url . '/' . $element;
                        $link->setAttribute('href', $newHref);
                    }
                }

                $content = $dom->saveHTML();
            } else {
                // Weiterleitung auf die Registrierungsseite, wenn custom_username nicht übereinstimmt
                if (!empty($registration_page_id)) {
                    wp_redirect(get_permalink($registration_page_id));
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: but...it is not safe to work as I no notice with other themes and plugins. I think there should be rewrite mods for that specific page, I guess.